# Python-pptx drawing a vertical line

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am trying to draw a vertical line using python-pptx module but haven't been able.

The below helps me draw a horizontal line but I am not sure how to get a vertical line in the slide

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE


prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[1])
line1 = slide.shapes.add_shape(MSO_SHAPE.LINE_INVERSE, Inches(6), Inches(6), Inches(1), Inches(2))
prs.save('sample.pptx')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `shapes.add_connector()`:
https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#pptx.shapes.shapetree.SlideShapes.add_connector

Its signature is:

```
add_connector(connector_type, begin_x, begin_y, end_x, end_y)
```

and it's used like this:

```
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_CONNECTOR
from pptx.util import Cm

line = slide.shapes.add_connector(
    MSO_CONNECTOR.STRAIGHT, Cm(2), Cm(2), Cm(10), Cm(10)
)
```

The first two length values specify the starting point and the remaining two specify the end point.

Comment: Cannot find reference 'MSO_CONNECTOR' in 'shapes.py'  - ???

Comment: It's not a typo. Check your import line and `python-pptx` installation. https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/master/pptx/enum/shapes.py#L642